# FB.getLoginStatus return authResponse null even after user login through Facebook login dialog

Tags: javascript, facebook

FB.getLoginStatus return authResponse as null, im unable to determine if i need to open the login dialog again. when user is prompt with login dialog again the previous permission is being reseted. For example, when user agree to allow app to manage a particular page. When login dialog is prompt again, they are unable to see the page that is previous approve for manage_pages permission. Re-login revoke the permission to manage that particular pages.

What can i do to prevent Facebook to prompt login dialog again? I am using v3.3 for facebook login:

```
checkLoginState(){
    var self = this;
    window.FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        console.log( 'login status' + JSON.stringify(response));
        if(response.authResponse === null){
            self.showLogin();
        }
    }, true);    
}


showLogin(){
        var self = this;
        // //fb permission scope and login function
        window.FB.login(function(response){
            console.log('has access token', response.authResponse)
          if (response.authResponse) {
                  console.log('has access token' + response.authResponse.accessToken);
                  self.setState({
                      fb_access_token: response.authResponse.accessToken
                  })
                    console.log('self.state', self.state)
                  self.storeFBToken();
                  self.retrieveFbProfile();
           } else {
                  console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
           }

      }, {scope: 'public_profile, manage_pages, email, pages_messaging, pages_show_list'});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with a production facebook app id and test it on a https page. getLoginStatus is returning access token correctly. it is still unknown to me why getLoginStatus does not work with a development facebook app id on localhost.

Comment: `localhost` should be exempt from the requirement to use HTTPS, but when HTTP gets used, it appears there is some bug with getLoginStatus specifically. (There was a similar thread about this a couple of days ago, can’t find it right now.) Probably easiest to work around, if you use a service like https://ngrok.com/ to provide a working HTTPS tunnel to your local machine.

Comment: you can also use devcert to generate a local certificate. that way, you can use localhost with https directly, without ngrok.